# opening a modal is returning result rather then after closing a modal

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog

The controller 'somePopupCtrl' is returning true as soon as the modal is opened rather then after the modal is closed.

Here is the code-

```
controller('somePopupCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
function delete() {
  var retVal = true;

  retVal = calculateRetCal();

 if(retVal) {
  var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                    templateUrl: 'removeData.html', 
                    controller: 'removeDataPopupCtrl',
                    backdrop : 'static'
                });

// want to return true for the delete() method when modal is closed.
modalInstance.result.then(function (data) {
 return true;
});
} else {
 return false;
}
 return retVal;
} 
}
```

Method `delete()` is returning either true or false and based on that we are hiding/showing on UI.

However, the UI is `hiding/showing` instantly when modal is opened rather then after modal is closed. So `modalInstance.result.then` code does not take its effect.

Is it happening may be because `modalInstance.result.then` is asynchronous call?

How to return from method only when modal is closed?

Answer (score 0):

return statement doesn't work as expected with promise. your return statement will not wait to complete the model instance result function. This is how asynchronous functions work.

You should pass a callback function to delete and call it something like this.

Sorry, I didn't run this but logic is correct.

```js
function delete(callback) {
  var retVal = true;

  retVal = calculateRetCal();

 if(retVal) {
  var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                    templateUrl: 'removeData.html', 
                    controller: 'removeDataPopupCtrl',
                    backdrop : 'static'
                });

// want to return true for the delete() method when modal is closed.
modalInstance.result.then(function (data) {
 callback(true);
});
} else {
 callback(false)
}
 callback(retVal)
} 

delete(function(response){
  console.log(response);
  //do what u want when you get response as true/false
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not convert from async to sync code, no way. Most flexible approach is to always return promise:

```
if(retVal) {
  return $modal.open({
                    templateUrl: 'removeData.html', 
                    controller: 'removeDataPopupCtrl',
                    backdrop : 'static'
                }).result;
} else {
  return $q.reject('was not opened, or smth');
}
```

P.S. In general `$modal` may be closed, so `$modal().result` is rejected (your then() wont run) and as it is very to miss such cases, you always return promise and chain.

P.P.S. When you return $q.reject or $q.when - you pay with 1 additional digest comparing to fully sync code. If you want to avoid that, you can use callbacks suggested above or promise $$state.status property.

Comment: As soon as I open the modal, the true is returned and UI hides the particular view element. So this solution didn't work. The hiding of element from a view should happen only when opened dialog is closed.

Comment: y, i forgot to add .result, updated. This not solution, but just example how you may manage situations when you have conditionally sync and async code.